# Counting primary Key ID and truncating on month creation date but getting duplicates on the counts

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server and am trying to get counts of an ID that is the primary key from a table and doing a date truncation by month on the creation date as follows:

```
Count (CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 1 THEN id END) AS Jan,   
Count  (CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 2 THEN id END) AS Feb,   
Count  (CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 3 THEN id END) AS Mar, 

etc.
```

The counts are coming back with duplicates. In other words I know that the counts are way too high.

I am joining other tables for some other data but that data seems to be coming back correctly.

Any thoughts?

I'm used to PostgreSQL and this function is much easier in that environment. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're joining to other tables, you may be getting duplicate "id" values and just counting total number of instances instead of unique instances. Change your SQL to the following:

```
Count (DISTINCT CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 1 THEN id END) AS Jan,
Count (CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 2 THEN id END) AS Feb,
Count (CASE MONTH (creation_date) WHEN 3 THEN id END) AS Mar, etc.
```